# Searching for a file named "test (').txt"

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I'm using dotnetzip in my app and I've got an issue report on a crash with files containing '(' and ')'

```
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("test.zip"))
            {
                var e = zip.SelectEntries("test (').txt"); //System.ArgumentException
                e = zip.SelectEntries("name = test (').txt"); //System.ArgumentException
                e = zip.SelectEntries("(name = test (').txt)"); //System.ArgumentException

                e = zip.SelectEntries( "'test ()'" ); // OK
                e = zip.SelectEntries( "'test (')'" ); //System.ArgumentException
                e = zip.SelectEntries( "test ()" ); //System.ArgumentException
            }
```

How can I select these files ?

```
zip.SelectEntries( "name = test (').txt)" )
'zip.SelectEntries( "name = test (').txt)" )' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HResult: -2147024809
HelpLink: null
InnerException: null
Message: "'name\u0006=\u0006test\u0006(''"
ParamName: null
Source: "Ionic.Zip"
StackTrace: "   at Ionic.FileSelector._ParseCriterion(String s)\r\n   at Ionic.FileSelector..ctor(String selectionCriteria, Boolean traverseDirectoryReparsePoints)\r\n   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.SelectEntries(String selectionCriteria)"
TargetSite: {Ionic.SelectionCriterion _ParseCriterion(System.String)}
```

Comment: What does the message of the exception say?

Comment: Exception details added

Comment: Seems the query handling of that zip library treats single quotes explicitly to do ... something. Could you try prefixing your string with `@` and adding a slash in front of the quote? Like `@"name = test(\').txt"` ?

Comment: No, same error. I added a new test case in description

Comment: Well, then you're left with iterating over all the files and doing the search outside of the library instead.

Comment: The single quote has aa special meaning; [To specify a name pattern that includes spaces, use single quotes around the pattern.](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/4469abe7-8fa4-101e-975d-305d2fd0affb.htm) But I'm not sure how to escape this character

Comment: I can add singles quotes, but this break files with single quotes in name. I don't know how to escape the single quote...

Comment: Looking at the source for Ionic/Zip/FileSelector.cs I don't think you can work around it. except maybe '[\x20]' could work, but i haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't find a solution with SelectEntries.

As suggested by Lasse V. Karlsen, I do the search outside the zip Library. As I'm only looking for a single file, this is straightforward:

```
var e = zip.Entries.FirstOrDefault(s => s.FileName == "test (').txt");
```

Note that if you have subfolders in zip, you must convert backslash to slash:

```
string name=@"(=')\test (').txt"
var e = zip.Entries.FirstOrDefault(s => s.FileName == name.Key.Replace(@"\", @"/"));
```